# Find the matrix representation $T:R^2\rightarrow P^2$ if the basis is given

Tags: linear-transformations

Find the matrix representation $T:R^2\rightarrow P^2$ if the basis is given $B_{R^2}=\{[2,0],[0,-2]\}$,  $B_{R^2}=\{2t^2-1,t+3,2\}$ and $T\{[a,b]\}=(a^2+b^2)t^2+(a-c)t+ab$
Please help me,but i didnt know how to do. Help me!!

I know how to find:

$T\{B_{R^2}\}=T\{[2,0]\}=(a^2+b^2)t^2+(a-c)t+ab$ and $T\{B_{R^2}\}=T\{[0,-2]\}=(a^2+b^2)t^2+(a-c)t+ab$ ?????

$T\{B_{P^2}\}=((2t-1)^2+(t+3)^2)t^2+(2t^2-1-2)t+(2t^2-1)(t+3)=4t^6-3t^4+10t^3+16t^2-4t-3$

but how to continue

Comment: can anyone help me

Comment: Are you sure it is $a-c$??

Comment: The vectors have the same image if that $c$ is $b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $\text{dim}(\mathbb R^2)=2$ and $\text{dim}(\mathbb R_{\le 2}[x])=3\implies$ the representative matrix of the map is such that $\mathcal M(T)\in \operatorname{M}(3\times 2,\mathbb R)$.
Let $T$ be your map and $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal D$ the bases of the two vector spaces, then
$$(2,0)\overset{T}{\mapsto} 4t^2+2t=2(2t^2-1)+2(t-3)+4\cdot2$$
$$(0,-2)\overset{T}{\mapsto} 4t^2+2t=T((2,0))\implies$$
$$\mathcal M(T)=\begin{pmatrix}2 &&2\\2 && 2\\4&&4 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Tell me if the text of the problem is fine.